# Series of divs, where on each one is stacked a black div with transparency, with a centered text

Tags: html, css

I have to display on the mobile view for a webpage a list of `div`s, where each of them has a specific `background-image` and central `h1` where I display the title. Stacked on each of these `div`s with the background-image, there is a black `div` with an `opacity: 0.5` to make the image darker.

This is the my code:

```css
.square-container {
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.square {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  color: white;
}

.hover-square {
  background: black;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square-logo {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1 {
  height: 87.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100vmin;
  margin: 4px auto;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}

.square h1.first {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square" style="background-color: #e74c3c">
    <div class="hover-square"></div>
    <h1 class="first">Case 1</h1>
    <img class="square-logo" src="//pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

It is correctly working, but the title is kept below the black `div`. I have tried to modify the `z-index` of the `h1` tag, but I had no luck so far. Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6naww073/) with the complete code. Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one mix elements (siblings) where some have a position other than `static`, they end up in a higher layer, hence, in your case, the `h1` sits behind.

As mentioned, for `z-index` to work it need a position (other than `static`), though one rarely need to use `z-index`, instead make sure all, or none, has a position, so in your case, simply drop `z-index` and add `position: relative`

```css
.square-container {
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.square {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  color: white;
}

.hover-square {
  background: black;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square-logo {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 87.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100vmin;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.square h1.first {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square" style="background-color: #e74c3c">
    <div class="hover-square"></div>
    <h1 class="first">Case 1</h1>
    <img class="square-logo" src="//pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the sole purpose of the `hover-square` is to darken the `square`, you could use a pseudo element instead, and save some markup and gain some flexibility

```css
.square-container {
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  color: white;
}

.square::before {          /*  added/changed to pseudo */
  content: '';
  background: black;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.square-logo {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 87.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100vmin;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.square h1.first {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square" style="background-color: #e74c3c">
    <h1 class="first">Case 1</h1>
    <img class="square-logo" src="//pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All solution are correct, but yours also gives me a new option. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `position: relative`

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/6naww073/1/)**

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 87.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100vmin;
  margin: 4px auto;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `z-index` to work you need to create stacking context and the easiest way to do this in this case is to just set `position: relative` on `h1` element.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6naww073/3/)

But if you want `h1` under navbar then you also need to set higher `z-index` on navbar so if `h1` is 10 then navbar must be 11.